# c# - Is it possible to check the target platform (winexe, exe, library and so on) during compilation

Tags: c#, compilation, precompile, pre-compilation

I found this MSDN help page
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swfss70d(v=vs.90).aspx

but this

```
#if TARGET = "library"
// Do something
#else
// Do something else
#endif
```

does not work.

Comment: Maybe you should try that with something else than `[AssemblyCulture]`. You're not supposed to mark your assembly as a satellite yourself and, quoth [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycultureattribute.aspx), *labeling a traditional code library with this attribute will break it, because no other code will be able to find the library's entry points at runtime*.

Comment: I fixed the question, that was only an example

Comment: An MSDN page that is specific to VB.NET is not going to be helpful.  In C# you have to do this yourself.  Try not to sweat the small stuff, it is just a simple project setting.

Comment: @HansPassant, for sure I won't stop a development of a project because of it! :) Sometime I'd like to know things without any pratical reason not because I need it. In this case for me it's interesting also because there is a thing that VB does and C# not.